# What is this 4-pin-power probe-like thing?

Tags: hardware, desktop

[image: probe-like thing]

On the wire, it says (approximately) `TSW1104 4305`. The power plug looks like a standard desktop 4-pin.

I found it in a box of random components. I've no idea where or when I got it, and my attempts to Google it by image and by the cable marking have failed. Hopefully someone reading this recognizes what it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a heat element/cartridge, like used for 3d printers. The power plug is there to handle some load (not a lot, but more than a circuit and hthis literlaly looks like...

https://www.amazon.co.uk/3D-Printer-Heating-Element-Cartridge/dp/B00M85KTO2
or
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B082HV788B/ref=sspa_dk_detail_5?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B082HV788B&pd_rd_w=JXkDo&pf_rd_p=1055d8b2-c10c-4d7d-b50d-96300553e15d&pd_rd_wg=gk7A6&pf_rd_r=0TBN1SX9BPWYPVQZX618&pd_rd_r=70b4252c-fc4d-415f-95e9-499e144db6f4&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFHNlJVRTVLSUZHQ0wmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTA0Njc4MzEyNEFKQVlCVVJIVlQyJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA5NTAzMzIyWjhLNEhJWFpZMUxVJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfZGV0YWlsJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==

Not sure how this ends up in a box or RANDOM elements.

They are used to heat up the "hotend" (the part where plastic is melted) in a FDM 3d printer and depending on type can go up to 500 degrees (though this one does not look to be a high temperature one).

Comment: FWIW, I don't have a 3D printer or anything like it, and never have. I guess there's a remote possibility that someone else's came to be in my boxes of components, but it seems unlikely. However, I could easily test this, with oven gloves on…

Comment: Well, I don't really care what you had or have and how that part ended up in that box. You put a part out, I THINK it may be this type of part and provided photos. The resit is not what we do here. Maybe it came from some other source that requires heat. i definitely does look like a heat cartridge, down to the "high" wattage connector. Note that I say high because even the high temperature ones are not likely to pull even 100 watt. Most rate 25 watt or lower. IIRC that one would run on 12 or 24 volt. That is what most printers use.